# Ternary operator with "OR" operator not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ternary-operator, or-operator

```
 {this.state.accordian === "Updated Port Entry" || "Updated Shipper Updates" ||  "Updated MT Container Details" ? 

    <li className="remove">
            <a role="button" className="boxs-close" onClick={this.Depottoggle.bind(this)}><i className="zmdi zmdi-plus collapseColor"></i></a>
    </li> : null}
```

In the state `this.state.accordian` having "Updated Truck Details".
As I am checking based on 
a) Updated Port Entry
b) Updated Shipper Updates
c) Updated MT Container Details

as It is not matched It should not be shown but I am able to see the Icon.

Please guide me.

Comment: you have to check each one against `accordian`

Comment: That should be `this.state.accordian === "Updated Port Entry" || this.state.accordian === "Updated Shipper Updates" ||  this.state.accordian === "Updated MT Container Details" `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `this.state.accordian` each time you compare it.

`this.state.accordian === "Updated Port Entry" || this.state.accordian === "Updated Shipper Updates" || this.state.accordian ===  "Updated MT Container Details"`